# How to add in double quotation first word of each line via sed?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have files with similar content but I want to make it a valid JSON I need to add every word of a line in a double quotation mark.
I tried existing answers on StackOverflow but none of them works properly.

```
{container:"proxy",
 endpoint:"proxy",
 exception:"ApiException"}
```

transfer to the following format:

```
  {"container":"proxy",
     "endpoint":"proxy",
     "exception":"ApiException"}
```

Comment: With any luck, the files can be treated as valid `jq` filters: `jq -nf pseudojson.txt` should output properly formatted JSON. There are lots of corner cases where this could fail, but probably no worse than trying to parse the data yourself and far easier.

Comment: unfortunately not, jq can't parse it since it's not a valid JSON format.

Comment: I didn't say to parse it as JSON; I said to use it as a `jq` filter which will *create* JSON. `-f` reads the filter from a file instead of supplying it on the command line, and `-n` prevents `jq` from trying to read from standard input. Your pseudo-JSON looks very much like the filter to create an object. For example, `jq -n '{foo: "bar"}` outputs `{"foo": "bar"}`.

Comment: You are completely right! that works!

Comment: Glad to hear your input was well-behaved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to treat each file as a `jq` filter that generates an object. For example,

```
$ cat tmp.jq
{container:"proxy",
 endpoint:"proxy",
 exception:"ApiException",
 instance:"133.3.12.250:9030"}
$ jq -nf tmp.jq
{
  "container": "proxy",
  "endpoint": "proxy",
  "exception": "ApiException",
  "instance": "133.3.12.250:9030"
}
```